# Springboot Gradle project Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, spring-boot

When I run a spring boot java project in Eclipse, I am getting the below error. Error: `Could not find or load the main class` but the same jar is running when I run throw the command prompt with the command *"java -jar springbootproject.jar*".

Find the below run configuration.

[image]

find the error screenshot when I run in Eclipse and sts

[image]

the same jar is working in the command prompt as shown below

[image]

Comment: Show us the Gradle (or Maven) build script and Eclipse run task configuration

Comment: I have updated my question with the screenshot you asked pls verify

Comment: Does the Eclipse run target have some way to specify the runtime project or classpath? I'm not sure if an incorrect config would generate an error, it would in IntelliJ.

Comment: Can you share the source code repo? Or at least a small subset of it that duplicates the problem you are running into?